# SSRS Chrome error "Parameter cannot be blank" but works fine in I/E and in Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

Thanks in advance for reviewing!

We have a multi-valued parameter that should allow a blank value.  When we choose only the blank value option, Chrome is displaying a message stating the parameter cannot be blank.  However, this error doesn't happen in I/E nor Visual Studio.

We are using isnull to replace any null possibilities to "" to make sure null is not being passed.

Do you guys have any idea if there is some fix needed for chrome?

We are using SSRS 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [SSRS Fix for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ssrs-fix/gklhehemnkbjbccoeneabopaflildkah/reviews). Chrome is not full supported by SSRS.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511(v=sql.110).aspx

[image: screenshot]